# General attribute accessor for a model in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is there a way to set up an accessor that is executed for all model attributes? Im using laravel 5.

For example:

```
class FooBar extends Model
{
    /**
     * foo accessor
     */
    public function getFooAttribute($value){
        return doSomething($value);
    }

    /**
     * bar accessor
     */
    public function getBarAttribute($value){
        return doSomething2($value);
    }

    /**
     * Access all attributes for this model (?)
     */
    public function getAllAttributes($value){
        return strtoupper($value);
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't get it, could you please be more specific?

Comment: @manix Lets pretend you're accessing the attribute `$fooBar->foo` (*$fooBar*  is an instance of the class above). The method _getFooAttribute_ will executed before return the value, right?

Now, in the same call, I want _getAllAttributes_ to be executed aswell, without calling it explicitly. So, when we access `$fooBar->foo`, _getFooAttribute_ will be executed and also _getAllAttributes_.